# Implications for explicitly declaring node api function as asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

Given a node express application, we can declare the function in the api as asynchornous using 'async'.

```
app.get(/v1/user', async function(request, response) {
    response.status(200).send({ message: messageReturn });
});
```

To my understanding, this is useful if you use await on a function inside of the api. However if the api does not need to await anything, is there any implications (syntactical or performance), if any, compared to not calling this function as `async`? i.e. Can I just declare every api function as async instead of

```
app.get(/v1/user', function(request, response) {
    response.status(200).send({ message: messageReturn });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` function always returns a promise.

But, Express does NOT pay any attention to the return value from the handler or middleware that you pass `app.get()` or any other route or middleware registration.

So, you can use `async` when you NEED to use it so you can use `await` in the implementation of the function.  But, Expresss is not paying any attention to the returned promise and will not do anything with it.

> To my understanding, this is useful if you use await on a function inside of the api.

Yes.  And, this is the only reason to declare it `async`.

> However if the api does not need to await anything, is there any implications (syntactical or performance), if any, compared to not calling this function as async?

Probably not consequential on performance, but you're forcing the interpreter to do some extra overhead.  It's going to put a `try/catch` around your code and it's going to make a new promise that is hooked into both the `try/catch` and the return value.  Since that promise is not used, it's just wasted cycles for the interpreter as it has to create and garbage collect a new promise object for every request and it also will have some additional setup overhead internal to the interpreter to catch exceptions in the `async` function (because exceptions are turned into a rejected promise by the `async` function infrastructure).

> Can I just declare every api function as async

You "can".  But, I would argue you "shouldn't".  `async` has several specific purposes.  If your code doesn't need any of those purposes, then I would argue you shouldn't use it.